# Redirecting domains and all ports to static LAN ip on connect to a virtual router

Tags: routing

I am pretty new to this community and i hope i am posting my question to the right place!

I am wondering of the following thing.

I have one REAL IP and i can asing many domains to it.

I have many virtual machines and i want to make one of them as a virtual router.

So i have the following idea:

**User types in browser: www.mydomain1.com (this domain has my REAL IP assigned) -> connects to my router/server -> Redirect to apache2 from VPS1 (LAN ip 192.168.0.101)
User types in browser: www.mydomain2.com (this domain has my REAL IP assigned) -> connects to my router/server -> Redirect to apache2 from VPS3 (LAN ip 192.168.0.103)
User types in browser: www.mydomain3.com (this domain has my REAL IP assigned) -> connects to my router/server -> Redirect to apache2 from VPS2 (LAN ip 192.168.0.102**)

Is this somehow possible with apache2 or something else ?

Note that the most important thing here is not only to redirect port 80 to the static lan IP when domain is connected to the router machine but all other ports and what is the best way if it is possible to make it ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a reverse-proxy, and is relatively easy to accomplish.

Apache's [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html), [Nginx](http://nginx.org) or [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org) can all do it.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to redirect all the traffic depending of the hostname because that hostname only exists in the application layer, and only in some protocols. You don't have any destination hostname in IP or TCP, so you cannot forward them as you want.

You could do that with HTTP as part of an HTTP is the hostname to which the client is connecting, but in other protocols that's not possible (e.g. in FTP you don't specify the hostname). To achieve that with HTTP you could use a reverse proxy like [nginx](http://nginx.org/), [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) or [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/).